# How to increase the default run time of a Cloud Run service invoked via Firebase

Tags: node.js, json, google-cloud-run

I have a few services in Google Cloud Run.

Now, I needed to invoke my services via paths such that

https://api.myapp.com/users Invokes the User Service

https://api.myapp.com/payments Invokes the Payment Service.

As I couldn't figure out a clean way to do this on Google Cloud Run I had to do it via Firebase hosting using the following `firebase.json` configuration:

...

```
"rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**/users/**",
          "run": {
            "serviceId": "user-service",
            "region": "us-east1"
          }
        },
        {
          "source": "**/payments/**",
          "run": {
            "serviceId": "payment-service",
            "region": "us-east1"
          }
        },
...
```

However,I quickly noticed something with the above setup.

It turns out that the default run time when the service was invoked via the above firebase mapping is 60seconds after which the service times out.

But if I am using the default service url to invoke the service it only times out after 15mins.

Is there a way to make firebase stick to the default 15mins from cloud run even though I am invoking the services via firebase?

Comment: Define what you mean by **timeout** and **default run time**.

Comment: Cloud Run function times out after 300s when invoked directly whereas when invoked via firebase hosting it times out after 60s. That what I meant by default run times

Comment: Do you mean **maximum execution time**? I am not sure about Firebase, but for Cloud Run setting that value is a deployment option.

Comment: Yes, I meant maximum execution time

Comment: Edit your question and show how you are deploying Cloud Run.

Comment: Your question is not clear about what is timing out. Is it the request, the Cloud Run instance, etc? Edit your question with details on the exact problem.